# Catch iframe exceptions

Tags: javascript, html, exception, iframe

When I set the `src` attribute on an iframe, sometimes an error is logged to the console (seems to be an uncaught exception), and the destination never loads.

For example, if I set `myiframe.src = 'http://www.google.com'`, it just never loads and my Chrome developer tools will log the following message:

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

I understand what this error is, but I want to catch this exception so I can handle it when a website doesn't want to be loaded into an iframe.

Because setting an iframe `src` is semi-asynchronous, I can't just surround that line with a try catch.

How do I handle iframe errors? `iframe.onerror` and `iframe.onabort` don't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Alternatively you could XmlHttpRequest and inject the response into the iframe with document.write..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options  this may be help you

Comment: so, to add here, iframe doesn't trigger onerror upon having an error, error handling has to be done in an onload handler as per https://javascript.info/onload-onerror#other-resources
`<iframe> Only load event when the iframe loading finished. It triggers both for successful load and in case of an error. That’s for historical reasons.`

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror

This is essentially a global, fallback error handler. Google around a bit for more information on how to use this one, but note that there are cross-browser compatibility issues with this approach that you must address, particularly the IE browser family.

This may or may not work well with IFRAME elements, so YMMV.

**UPDATE:**

Take a look at this question.

[How to catch JavaScript errors in all Iframes (with window.error)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353664/how-to-catch-javascript-errors-in-all-iframes-with-window-error)

Comment: `window.onerror` doesn't seem to catch it. Also, like I mentioned on the post, `iframe.onerror` doesn't get it either :(

Comment: I'll try playing around with this and update if I find anything interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, window.onerror doesn't catch it.