# Catching exception in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, exception, iframe

I have configured the following iframe.

```
var iframe = $("<iframe style='display:none;' />");
```

When I change the src, the iframe loads, but I'm having a hard time catching the exception.

```
iframe.attr("src", url);
```

If I load the iframe with the 'load' function, it does catch the exception, but I need the code to be synchronous, not in ajax.

```
iframe.load(url, {}, function (data, status) {
   // status will be error if an exception has been thrown
});
```

However, if I run the following example, I cannot get the status of the call.

```
iframe.load(function  (param1, param2) {
   // param2 will be empty
});
```

Comment: How about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1353967/2040487)?