# How to catch all errors in web content by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input: source html file, with JavaScript code and with possible errors in web content.
Output: JavaScript code, that will print in alert the first error it can catch, after injecting into source html file.

I need to catch all errors that might pop up on web page by using JavaScript, here is non-exhaustive list of errors I need to register:

- JavaScript errors
- all image errors(image is not available, etc.)
- iframes errors(source is not available, etc.)
- other errors

On the first iteration it will be perfect to catch just JavaScript errors(can be done with window.onerror) and Image source errors.

Comment: What research have you done on this topic so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch all javascript errors and send them to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328154/catch-all-javascript-errors-and-send-them-to-server)

Comment: There are answers for all of those requirements in SO already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328154/catch-all-javascript-errors-and-send-them-to-server, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815762/detect-when-an-image-fails-to-load-in-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353664/how-to-catch-javascript-errors-in-all-iframes-with-window-error...

Comment: I have an input of html code, possibly with JS. From this in order to get output I need to inject JS, which triggers when one of mentioned errors pops up.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onerror = function(msg) {
    alert('Error message: '+msg');
    return true;
}
```

For the list of error u should initialise an array and push all the error to that and finally check that array periodically. once the error shown in popup clear the data.

Hope it helps u.